# Como pesquisar por palavras semelhantes ou sinônimos no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, postgresql, algoritmo-de-busca

**Preciso fazer com que uma pesquisa me retorne palavras semelhantes**

Encontrei a pesquisa fonética ela pode até ser usada para refinar a busca que preciso, mas acho que isso não é o ideal.

Por exemplo, em um banco de dados tenho vários profissionais, mas sua experiência profissional não corresponde a nenhum padrão de palavras.

Ao fazer a busca: "Gerente Supermercado", gostaria de conseguir resultados como:

- "Gerente de Supermercados"
- "Gerência de Supermercados"
- "Diretor de Supermercado"

Alguém teria alguma sugestão?

Obrigado

Comment: O que você precisa aparentemente é busca semântica. Não me lembro de ver nada nativo para isto no `PostgreSQL`, mas apenas coisas como `Semantic MediaWiki`. Também, existem soluções mais "parrudas" que possuem esta funcionalidade, como as baseadas em `Lucene` (Hibernate Search e Solr, por exemplo).

Comment: Obrigado Bruno César, pesquisarei sobre essas ferramentas.

Comment: OK, só confirma se é por aí mesmo o que você precisa, caso escolha por algo usando lucene posso lhe ajudar postando alguma coisa para iniciar.

Comment: @BrunoCésar, me parece que o caminho a ser seguido é a busca semântica mesmo. Mas para isso eu preciso preparar minha própria base de conhecimento ou consigo usar algum mecanismo que já me traga as informações a serem comparadas na minha busca? 
Sobre o PostgreSQL, encontrei um artigo que trata do tsvector e full text search, mas nao entendi muito bem como montar essa estrutura e alimentar com as informações que tenho.

Comment: O `Solr` já possui dicionário de algumas coisas mais comuns Rafael, existe inclusive para a língua portuguesa e você pode melhorá-lo, criando seu próprio dicionário. Coisas que você deve considerar são stemização ([na análise linguística](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Language+Analysis)) e o uso de [sinônimos](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilterFactory.html). Para criar isto, você pode inclusive trabalhar com aprendizado de máquina. Enfim, existem várias formas.

Comment: No PostgreSQL `tsvector` é uma função para extrair o lexema a partir de algumas strings, parece interessante começar por isto, nunca usei e não sei detalhes sobre o comportamento dele. Esta função é uma das disponíveis no PostgreSQL para `full text`, técnica para busca que se diferencia da comum por que é baseada em metadados e em outras coisas como documentos e tal. Veja [isto](http://skytools.projects.pgfoundry.org/txid/functions-textsearch.html), talvez ajude a usar full-text no PostgreSQL. Se eu conseguir algum tempo, testo isso no PostgreSQL a partir de dicionários que uso no lucene.

Answer (score -1):

Rafael,

Acredito que você conseguirá isso usando Full Text Search. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html

```
select * 
from tabela 
where to_tsvector('portuguese', campo_text) @@ to_tsquery('portuguese', 'Gerente & Supermercado')
```

A depender da quantidade de informações a processar você pode criar uma coluna em sua tabela do tipo tsvector, dessa forma você só precisaria usar o `to_tsquery()` no `where` com o conteúdo da consulta.

Espero ter ajudado :)